# How to add a string to then beginning of binary file

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a binary file.

I want to add binary size to the beginning of the binary file.

but I can't find the way.

So I decided to create a new file that size of binary + original binary file.

but that trying is failed:

```
void addSizeToHeader(char file_name[], off_t size)
{
    // add size of file to beginning of the new file created
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("{new file}", "ab");
    fseek(fp2, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(fp2, "%ld", size);
    

    // add origin file to new the file. 
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long int size_file = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size_file+1);
    memset(buffer, 0, size_file+1);
    printf("%d\n", size_file);
    fread(buffer,size_file ,1, fp)
    fprintf(fp2, "%s", buffer);
    
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    free(buffer);
 
}
```

That function received two parameters. The one is the name of the file and the other is size of that file.

I want to create a new file the two things are concatenated.

Please advise me.

Comment: `fprintf(fp2, "%s", buffer);` you can't use `fprintf` for binary data.Use `fwrite` instead.

Comment: In addition: you absolutely need to check if `fopen` fails. Not doing so is not an option.

Comment: Also: `fread(buffer,*size_file ,1, fp` -> `fread(buffer,*size_file ,1, fp`, didn't you get a compile error?

Comment: @Jabberwocky *size_file is just typing error lol. okay I will check if fopen() fails

Comment: If you use `fread()` to read binary contents of a file, you should also use `fwrite()` to write that contents as binary into the copy. `fprintf()` expects a string that is a totally different beast.

Comment: How many bytes does `fprintf(fp2, "%ld", size);` write to your output file?  And how will any reading process know which ones they are?  The real question is, ***why*** are you adding the size of the file to the beginning of the file.  If you have the file, you already know how big it is.

Comment: @thebusybee Thank you! I learned a new thing

Comment: @AndrewHenle I need a binary file that can be divided into 12bytes totally because of my security algorithm. So I should add dummy variables to the binary file.  So I need to know the ordinary size of the file later. So I need the above process.